# systemd ConditionPathExists for .socket files

Tags: sockets, systemd

I am using systemd to start up the Linux system.
I have a socket file (ssh.socket) for the ssh connection that should only be started when a certain file in the directory exists.

The variable for service files `ConditionPathExists` seems not to be supported for socket files.

Is there an easy way with systemd to open the socket only when the file exists?

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty sure on the support of `ConditionPathExists` support for socket unit files.
But a way out would be to create a service file that accepts `ConditionPathExists` and add this service dependency for your socket file using `After` and `Requires`.
Hope this works.